# What does "rapamycin-sensitive oncogenic transformation" mean?

Tags: biochemistry, cancer

Can someone explain exactly what "rapamycin-sensitive oncogenic transformation" is? I get that it's a drug that suppresses the immune system but what does it have to do with oncogenic transformation?

Here's the article where they talk about it:

http://www.pnas.org/content/104/13/5569.full

Comment: i am not particularly sure but it could be related to dysregulation of the mTOR pathway.. mTOR pathway is involved in survival in stress..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mammalian target of [rapamycin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapamycin) ([mTOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOR)) is a Ser/Thr [protein kinase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_kinase) that functions as an ATP and amino acid sensor to balance nutrient availability and cell growth. When sufficient nutrients are available, mTOR responds to a [phosphatidic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphatidic_acid)-mediated signal to transmit a positive signal to [p70 S6 kinase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P70S6_kinase) and participate in the inactivation of the [eIF4E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIF4E) inhibitor, [4E-BP1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIF4EBP1). These events result in the translation of specific mRNA subpopulations. mTOR is phosphorylated via the [PI3 kinase/Akt signaling pathway](http://www.cellsignal.com/pathways/akt-signaling.jsp) and also autophosphorylates under translationally repressive conditions. mTOR plays a key role in cell growth and homeostasis and may be abnormally regulated in tumors. It is currently under investigation as a potential target for anti-cancer therapy.

The [mTOR signaling pathway](http://www.cellsignal.com/pathways/translational-control.jsp?pathway=trans-mtor) shows how mTOR is involved in numerous cell processes that can be dysregulated in cancer, including cell growth, proliferation, angiogenesis, [autophagy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autophagy), and various kinds of metabolism. "*Rapamycin-sensitive oncogenic transformation*" therefore means that the transformed cells still have intact "wild-type" mTOR complexes that can be down-regulated by the tumor-specific administration of rapamycin analogues, hence inhibiting the above-mentioned processes and arresting or killing the cells.